# Let $f$ be a measurable function on $E$ that is finite a.e on $E$. Show that there is measurable set $F$ such that $m( E \setminus F)<\varepsilon$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

The following problem is from Royden's real analysis book.

> Let $f$ be a measurable function on $E$ that is finite a.e on $E$ and $m(E) < \infty$. For each $\varepsilon >0$, show that there is measurable set $F$ contained in $E$ such that $f$ is bounded on $F$ and $m( E \setminus F)<\varepsilon$.

Since $f$ is finite a.e on $E$ we have that $m(\{ x \in E \mid \text{$f(x)$ not finite} \})=0$. The task seems now to be finding this set $\{ x \in E \mid \text{$f(x)$ not finite} \}$. If I define $$E_k=\{x \in E \mid|f(x)|< k \}$$ then isn't $$\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k=\{x \in E \mid |f(x)| < \infty\}$$ that is $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k$ the set where $f$ is finite so $$E \setminus \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k$$ would be the set where $f$ is not finite? From here using the continuity of measure I have that $$0=m(E \setminus \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k)=m(  \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty E \setminus E_k) =\lim_{k\to \infty} m(E \setminus E_k)$$ and so $m(E \setminus E_k) < \varepsilon$ for $k \ge k_0$, where $k_0 \in \Bbb N$.

I also tought of defining $E_k$ as $$E_k=\{x \in E \mid |f(x)| > k \}$$ and I would have gotten that $$\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty E_k = \{x \in E \mid |f(x)| = \infty \}$$ that is $$\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty E_k = \{ x \in E \mid \text{$f(x)$ not finite} \} $$ but I guess this wouldn't work since I don't have any boundedness on $f$?

Comment: I would go with a proof by contradiction. If the claim was false, then there would be an $\epsilon_0>0$ such that for all sets $F$ on which $f$ is bounded we have $m(E\setminus F)\ge\epsilon_0$. Now, $f$ is bounded on each $E_k$. What does that imply then? Note that $E_k\subset E_{k+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the general fact that  given $A_1\supset A_2 \supset A_3 \supset \cdots$ with $m(A_1)<\infty$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}m(A_n)=m(\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n)$.

Let $A_n = \{x\in E \mid |f(x)|\ge n \}$, then $\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n = \{x\in E \mid |f(x)|=\infty\}=0$. Therefore for any $\epsilon>0$, there is $n$ such that $m(A_n)<\epsilon$, and $f$ is bounded by $n$ over $E\setminus A_n$.